# Is Javascript needed to play HTML 5 Videos in recent browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

Based on this page on w3schools I don't see any mention of Javascript being needed to play HTML5 videos on recent browsers.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Yet, when I disable Javascript on Safari, I can no longer play Videos embedded on my webpage via  Tag. I even disabled lazy loading on a test page to see if that helped, but it didn't.

My primary concern is visitors on Mobile devices so falling back to flash is not an option.

hence the question, Is Javascript needed on fairly recent browsers ? what are best fallback options without requiring any plugins ?

like, using  to provide direct download of Video, etc ?

Comment: It doesn't look required on Chrome. I disabled Javascript and was able to run the video on that page just fine

Comment: @CertainPerformance. Thanks, you are correct. It seems to work in Chrome and also in Firefox. Safari is still a problem and I'm yet to try Opera, IE and Edge. I hope the community has insights on Safari and other browsers for this.

Comment: That's a Safari bug. You can let them know here: https://bugs.webkit.org/ But I don't think you should have too much concerns about Safari users running without js.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido. OK, there is not much I can do about it if it isn't a problem on my server end. I'll report it as a bug.

Comment: @Curious101 just an update ... the original bug https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=178040 has been open a couple of years. I guess Apple aren't in a hurry to fix :(

Answer (score 0):

javascript is absolutely not required to play the video in html5 
the w3 video is not playing because it is rendering that part of the dom using js and also video is not local it is brought by anchor tag

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate on this ? In my case I have Video file hosted on Azure and am referencing that via <source src="" type="video/mp4"> tag. I see the poster render fine, and have a play or stop button on top of it. But when I press/click the button, nothing happens. To be clear same page works on Chrome and Firefox  with Javascript disabled, but on safari it refuses to play.

Comment: my guess in this case would be either an encoding, mime type, or header issue with the video if it's playing in Chrome/FF but not Safari on macOS (Safari on Windows isn't supported any more). Can you share the actual video URL (does it play in Safari if you just put the URL on the address bar?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal. Thanks, the video embedded in w3schools is behaving the same way. It does not play on safari with JS disabled. Here is the link from that embedded video: https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4

Comment: wow, replicated (not seen that before). I've filed a Safari bug (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=200433), might be worth tracking